# Updating Chart from Gridview - chart updates after Gridview Updates

Tags: c#, gridview, charts, sqldatasource

I have a GridView and a chart. I am plotting the time lapsed data from the Gridview.

[image]

**Problem:** The chart does not gets updated at the same time GridView does. It is always one step back (requires one extra click).

**Mechanism:** This is a time lapsed plot. There is a start and end date and I am plotting them in particular way. So I read the values in the Grid in page_load function

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
        {
         // read the values that I need from the Grid
         // and assign them to chart to create the chart
        }

GridView1.DateBind();
Char1.DataBind();
```

I tried the page refresh approach but that did not work. I am trying to figure out, am I doing something wrong? The 3D button works fine by the way and one of the thing it does wrong: it executes the actual query from SQLDataSource, not the one I created on the fly.

**Suspicion:** I am suspecting SQLDataSource for the problem. I have put one on ASPX page. I change the SQL Query on fly and I think that could be a problem?

Comment: What do you mean with "It is always one step back (requires one extra click)." ? 
Does it show the values from the previous search ?
If so could it be that you need to DataBind the GridView before you run the foreach to assing the Chart . . .

Comment: As you can see, there are values in GridView but those values are not populated in the chart. I have to click the search again, only then the chart gets populated. I have used DataBind() with both GridView and Chart where I have updated data in them.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using some UpdatePanel?

Maybe you can try something like this:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Column1");
dt.Columns.Add("Column2");

foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
{
    dt.Rows.Add(GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[0].Text, row.Cells[0].Text);
}

cht.DataSource = dt;

cht.Series["serie"].XValueMembers = "Column1";
cht.Series["serie"].YValueMembers = "Column2";

cht.DataBind();
```

Comment: No. Gridve SQL DataSource and Chard. It does have a master page.

Comment: Ok. So, is the chart's data based only in the foreach, or is it linked to the SqlDataSource too? I agree with you. I think there are something with your sqldatasource...

Comment: Chart is not attached to SQLDataSource. I am mapping the data manually using foreach.

Comment: Which chart component you are using?

Comment: This comes with [ASP.NET 3.5](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/11/24/new-asp-net-charting-control-lt-asp-chart-runat-quot-server-quot-gt.aspx).seperate install

Comment: I tried here, but using a Chart.DataSource (DataTable from selected lines in GridView), and the Chart.DataBind() works fine. Inside the foreach, you can try to add the values that you need in a DataTable, assign to DataSource of your chart, and then call DataBind(). How do you do the assign of values in chart? Is it complex?

Comment: DataTable from Gridview can actually be great tip. Can you post some of your code. I did not use DataSource property of chart because my chart is timeline not a bar or plain x vs y.

Comment: Humm I tried with a bar.. But the timeline wouldn't be different anyway. I'll edit my first post.